# React setState called multiple times on the same state object

Tags: reactjs

I have the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {render} from 'react-dom';

import Forms from './forms/forms.jsx';

class Option1 extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <p>Icon 1</p>
        )
    }
}

class TShirt extends React.Component {
    render () {
        console.log(this.props.currentState);
        return <div className="thsirt">
                    <h1>{this.props.name}</h1>
                    <p>{this.props.iconID}</p>
                    {this.props.optionA ? <Option1  /> : ''}
                </div>;
    }
}

class Link extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <li 
                data-id={this.props.el}
                onClick={this.props.onClick} 
                className={this.props.activeClass}>{this.props.el}
            </li>
        );
    }
}

class Nav extends React.Component {
    getComponentID (id) {
        switch(id) {
            case 'name':
                return 1;
                break;
            case 'color':
                return 2;
                break;
            case 'design':
                return 3;
                break;
            case 'share':
                return 4;
                break;
        }
    }
    handleClick (event) {
        // setting active class
        var id = event.target.getAttribute("data-id"); 
        this.props.action(id);

        // switching coomponent based on active class
        var component = this.getComponentID(id);
        this.props.switchComponent(component);
    }
    render () {
        var links = ['name', 'color', 'design', 'share'],
            newLinks = [],
            that = this;
        links.forEach(function(el){
            newLinks.push(<Link 
                            onClick={that.handleClick.bind(that)} 
                            activeClass={that.props.active == el ? 'active': ''} 
                            key={el} 
                            el={el} 
                          />
            );
        });
        return (
            <ol>
                {newLinks}
            </ol>
        );
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: '',
            color: '',
            active: '',
            formId: 1,
            optionA: {
                on: false,
                icon_id: '',
                option_id: '',
                name: ''
            }
        };
        this.setName = this.setName.bind(this);
        this.setColor = this.setColor.bind(this);
        this.setAtciveNavEl = this.setAtciveNavEl.bind(this);
        this.setFormId = this.setFormId.bind(this);

        this.setOptionA = this.setOptionA.bind(this);
        this.setOptionAVisibility = this.setOptionAVisibility.bind(this);
    }
    setName (tshirt) {
        this.setState({ name:tshirt })
    }
    setColor (color) {
        this.setState({ color:color })
    }
    setAtciveNavEl (el) {
        this.setState({ active:el })
    }
    setFormId (id) {
        this.setState({ formId:id })
    }

    setOptionA (iconID, iconName) {
        this.setState({ 
            optionA: 
            {
                icon_id: iconID,
                name: iconName
            } 
        })
    }
    setOptionAVisibility (onOff, optionID) {
        this.setState({ 
            optionA: 
            {
                option_id: optionID,
                on: onOff
            }
        })
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <section className={this.state.color}>
                <Nav 
                    active={this.state.active} 
                    action={this.setAtciveNavEl} 
                    switchComponent={this.setFormId} 
                />
                <TShirt 
                    name={this.state.name}
                    icons={this.state.options}

                    optionA={this.state.optionA.on}
                    currentState={this.state}
                />
                <Forms 
                    name={this.state.name} 
                    action={this.setName} 
                    colorVal={this.setColor} 
                    activeNav={this.setAtciveNavEl} 
                    switchComponent={this.setFormId}
                    formID={this.state.formId}

                    setOptionA={this.setOptionA}
                    setOptionAVisibility={this.setOptionAVisibility}
                />
            </section>
        );
    }
}

render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

I need to populate this object at different times like this:

```
    setOptionA (iconID, iconName) {
        this.setState({ 
            optionA: 
            {
                icon_id: iconID,
                name: iconName
            } 
        })
    }
    setOptionAVisibility (onOff, optionID) {
        this.setState({ 
            optionA: 
            {
                option_id: optionID,
                on: onOff
            }
        })
    }
```

The problem I have is taht when I console.log my state at:

```
class TShirt extends React.Component {
    render () {
        console.log(this.props.currentState);
        return <div className="thsirt">
                    <h1>{this.props.name}</h1>
                    <p>{this.props.iconID}</p>
                    {this.props.optionA ? <Option1  /> : ''}
                </div>;
    }
}
```

after all my click events it seems like I loose the "on" and "option_id" from the optionA object. 
Does calling setState on the same object override the previous setState?

Comment: Yes, setState overwrites the given key-value pairs.

Comment: Yes it's not smart enough to do a deep object comparison like that. You'll have to do something more clever (like get optionA out of state, modify it, then setState to it) in order to do what you want to do.

Comment: Lesson learned, thank you!!

Comment: @Alex you know you can use the spread operator since es2015 ? `this.setState({optionA: {...this.state.optionA, on: onOff} })` that will give you a copy of the whole item with just the extra value changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing ES2015, you can use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to copy the whole object and just modify one of it's properties:

```
setOptionAVisibility (onOff, optionID) {
    this.setState({ 
        optionA: 
        {
            ...this.state.optionA,
            option_id: optionID,
            on: onOff
        }
    })
}
```

Can be very useful when modifying single properties of complex objects on the state tree.